# How to avoid problems with security on Chili Editor integration?

Tags: linux

I am integrating Chili editor ( http://www.chili-publish.com/ ) with my website and I am getting some issues when I try to use an iframe pointing out to chili editor page hosted on a different server. 
Basically it does not let me to run javascript across domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you check the CHILI documentation you will discover some very helpful information
*"Setup cross domain scripting through Reverse Proxy"*

You should have your own log-in to the documentation portal, if not please contact your local reseller who should be able to assist.

FYI. 
In future there is also a great support portal for CHILI Publisher users.

Regards
Alan

Comment: I found the solution on the documentation a bit complicated so I implemented my own : 1 - Put this RW rules on .htaccess file -->RewriteRule ^/?chili/(.*)$ http://chili_Server_IP/CHILI/$1 [L,P]
RewriteRule ^/?CHILI/(.*)$ http://chili_Server_IP/CHILI/$1 [L,P]. 2 - change vhosts file ---> /etc/httpd/vhosts/default.config and add :

ProxyPreserveHost On